# Carmageddon TDR 2000 crashes in Send in the Sharks

Tags: technical-issues, carmageddon

*Carmageddon TDR 2000* has recently been made available through Steam with the upcoming release of *Carmageddon: Reincarnation*, but as with many old games, it doesn't work perfectly.

Although the first level plays fine, the second level, "Send in the Sharks", crashes on loading with the following message:

> Direct X Error 0x80070057

I'm running Windows 8.1 64-bit, and the game crashes when selecting either my GeForce GT 735M or Intel HD Graphics 4000.

Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [suggested on this forum](http://www.cwaboard.co.uk/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=6360), simply disabling the Mip Filter works around the crash.

1. Launch TDR 2000 Setup.
2. Select "Options".
3. Under "Display", select "Advanced >>".
4. Locate the option for "Mip Filter" and set it to "None".
5. Press OK and launch the game.

Comment: can you please accept this answer so the question won't show up in unanswered? thanks!